# Still can't get ShippingMethod in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a `app/design/frontend/hopnew/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml` file.  In it, all I wnat to do is get the shipping method that was set in the last form submission.  I've tried all these statements, but they all echo nothing:

```
<?php
echo $this->getAddressShippingMethod();
echo "111<br />";
echo $this->getAddress()->getShippingMethod();
echo "222<br />";
echo $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
echo "333<br />";                                                                                                                                                                            
echo $this->getCheckout()->getQuote();
echo "444<br />";          
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
echo "555<br />";

echo $this->getQuote();
echo "666<br />";

echo $this->getCheckout();
echo "777<br />";          
echo $this->getAddress();
echo "888<br />"; 
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
echo "999<br />";
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCheckout();
echo "10<br />";
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getAddress();
echo "11<br />";    
//          echo $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
echo "12<br />";
```

I've confirmed that `estimateUpdatePostAction()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` does indeed save the shipping method.

So now how do I grab it from my shipping.phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

To get shipping method from the last order

```
$order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();        
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$shipping_method = $order->getData("shipping_method");
```